# resizing uiscrollview contentSize, can't apply new value

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

i'm trying to resize my scroll view content size during runtime. i can do this if i actually set the values myself, but when i try to assign the new value after doing the calculations with the last object it doesn't work3!! i'm guessing it's because i'm not setting my int up properly. Any help is always appreciated guys

This works:

```
 [scroller setContentSize: CGSizeMake(scroller.frame.size.width ,scroller.frame.size.height*2)];
```

Not working:

```
int newHeight=textViewRect.origin.y+textViewRect.size.height+5;
     [scroller setContentSize: CGSizeMake(scroller.frame.size.width ,newHeight)];
```

EDIT:

```
 CGRect textViewRect=textView.frame;
textViewRect=CGRectMake(textViewRect.origin.x, textViewRect.origin.y, textViewRect.size.width, textViewRect.size.height);
```

MAYBE THIS:

would the newHeight value being wrong have anything to do with the fact i've got it in the viewDidLoad method?

Thanks for your help

Comment: what is the value of newHeight variable?

Comment: 67, but the textView starts at view.origin.y=66 and the height of the textView stretches below the view bounds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i have done is subclass uiwebview to use it as a textView. after passing the data to my subclass i load it into the web view, once this loads i then resize it's frame to the content size in the webViewDidFinishLoading method.

Because of this there was a few millisecond delay before the text view was added to the view, which mean't the value i was getting was 0. To get around this i added a delegate method to my subclass to notify me when it has finished loading. once it has finished loading i then resize the contentSize accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Put a breakpoint over the line

```
int newHeight=textViewRect.origin.y+textViewRect.size.height+5;
```

and find the value for the `newHeight`. If the value is less than `scroller`'s height, then you cannot scroll.

Comment: i'm confused as to why i need a breakpoint? i thought my problem was the assigning of the int is not correct

Comment: Usually breakpoint is used to find the value in each statement. You can also use the `NSLog` to find the value.

Comment: i tried that and my app crashes. i tried %i and %d for the string format

Comment: my bad i didn't format the string right. but the value for this object comes out at 67 but that cant be right as the text view is much much bigger. i'll have another look

Comment: Did  you try `NSLog(@"newHeight = %f", newHeight);` ? Also you can make that `newHeight` as float.

Comment: Changing that to float won't solve the problem. It was just a suggestion to maintain the data type. Try `NSLog(@"%@",textViewRect);` after the line `CGRect textViewRect=textView.frame;`

Comment: i've edited the question, i think it's because i have it in the view did load method

Comment: Actually that needs to done in viewDidLoad only if you have added the elements through nib file.

Comment: You check the properties of `textView` in nib file.

Comment: i've figured it out, i'll post my answer. thank you for your help